# Angular directive restrict by wildcard class name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to create a directive using just a *part* of a class like:

```
app.directive('js-', function(someService){
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      someService.setElement(element);
    }
});
```

`<div class="js-directive"></div>`
`<div class="js-same-directive"></div>`

The elements that are using the directive already have lots of attributes - so I'm thinking of ways to keep the markup a bit more terse.

Comment: I highly doubt it. Why not create a directive that reads the class name, eg `<div class="some-random-string" my-class-reading-directive></div>`

Comment: I already have something similar to that. I agree with you though - I highly doubt it too, but thought it would be worth asking about.